# Altium 17 somehow lost shortcuts, I cannot rotate a part with the spacebar

Tags: altium

In both the schematic and PCB I can no longer rotate a part 90 degrees by hitting the space bar.  I have tried lots of things, but getting to the context-sensitive help with ctrl-F1 also does not work.

I tried assigning 'space' the primary shortcut in edit command-> rotate selection,
but then it always prompts me for an angle.

I also know I should be able to select a part (which works) and then hit F1 or Control-F1 to bring up a context sensitive menu so I can change things like the shortcuts, but that key is also not assigned correctly so I cant get to the menu to change the shortcuts.

Help!?

Comment: Did you try ctrl+space?

Answer (score 1):

I am using 18 now (which might be wise to update to) but I thought I remember stumbling over this as well. If I remember correctly you have to click on the component and then rotate, not click and hold and then try and rotate within Schematics.

Whereas, in the PCB docs you have to click and hold and then hit space bar in order to rotate the component.

I see 17 is different then 18 but this shows how to get to the shortcut menu and reassign keys. 
https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/Altium+Designer+-+((Shortcut+Keys))

Also, you could reset your preferences in the preferences dialog and see if that helps as well.

Ultimately, I would recommend moving to 18 as it has some pretty cool features and then all the documents are easy to reference.